# PayPal payment from Business to Personal account

Tags: paypal

I know how to send money from Personal account to Business account (by using `paypal-rest-sdk`). But now I want to send money from Business account to a Personal account

Is there a product to support this type of payment

Answer (score 1):

> by using paypal-rest-sdk

The old PayPal-Node-SDK for receiving payments is deprecated, so you'd better mean the current Checkout-NodeJS-SDK.

For sending payments to another account, you can set the purchase_unit `payee` to [the email address of the receiving account](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/pay-another-account/).

If you wish to send payments from your a Business account in an automated fashion, the Business account owner can contact PayPal to inquire about [enabling Payouts](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/prerequisites/#get-access-to-paypal-payouts).

Comment: Thank you .Do you have any code example for this ?